# StackOverflow exception in my F# code

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I am hunting for a particular method in a group of assemblies. in order to find my method, I have written this code

```
module MethodNameExtractor

open System
open System.IO
open System.Reflection

let ListMethodsInAssembly (input : AssemblyName) =   
  try
    let appd = AppDomain.CreateDomain("temp")
    try    
      let assm = Assembly.Load(input)
      assm.GetTypes() 
      |> Array.toSeq
      |> Seq.fold (fun accm ty -> Seq.append accm (ty.GetMethods() |> Array.toSeq)) Seq.empty
      |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.Name <> "GetType" && x.Name <> "ToString" && x.Name <> "GetHashCode" && x.Name <> "GetType") 
    finally
      AppDomain.Unload(appd)
  with
  | :? System.Exception -> Seq.empty

let ListAllDlls = 
  let rec expandDir (parent : DirectoryInfo) accm =    
    let files = parent.GetFiles() |>  Array.toSeq |> Seq.map (fun f -> try Some(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName f.FullName) with | :? System.Exception -> None)
    let accm = Seq.append files accm
    let subDirs = parent.GetDirectories() |> Array.toSeq
    Seq.fold (fun accm d -> expandDir d accm) accm subDirs

  let basePath = "c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\\"
  let loc = ["GAC_64"; "GAC_MSIL";] |> List.toSeq  
  Seq.fold (fun acc l ->
      let path = basePath + l
      expandDir (new DirectoryInfo(path)) acc
    ) 
    Seq.empty
    loc


[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =   
  ListAllDlls 
  |> Seq.fold (
      fun accm x -> 
        match x with 
        | Some(a) -> Seq.append accm (ListMethodsInAssembly a)
        | None -> accm
    ) Seq.empty  
  |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%s" x.Name)
  0
```

My hope was that since I am using Sequences and Tail Recursion.... I should not be consuming much memory and if I could leave my code running long enough, I could get a list of methods in all the assemblies.

My code is pretty straight forward... get a list of DLLs in all the directories and subdirectories.

Load DLL and get Types... and then from Types get all public methods...

But the code processes approx 2 million records and then gets StackOverflow Exception.

I am already using Tail recursion and Sequence... How can I further improve this code?

Comment: I'm not used to looking at F# code, but a [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) is generally going to be because your recursion is infinite or goes too deep.

Comment: Your `expandDir` call is recursive, but it isn't a [tail call](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx). This will likely lead to a SOE if the stack gets deep enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- Your combination of `Seq.fold`, `Seq.append` and `Seq.empty` is a poor implementation of `Seq.collect` or `yield!` in sequence expression.
- You don't need options here, just skip generation in sequence expression or use Seq.choose.
- You don't need `Array.toSeq` or `List.toSeq` when you apply functions on sequences to lists/arrays.

  - `try ... with | :? System.Exception` can be shortened to `try ... with _`

Your `expandDir` function isn't tail-recursive. If you change it to use **sequence expression**, it is optimized using CPS so StackOverflow doesn't happen.

Here is an improved version. I think it is more readable and probably faster.

```
let ListMethodsInAssembly (input : AssemblyName) =   
  try
    let appd = AppDomain.CreateDomain("temp")
    try    
      let assm = Assembly.Load(input)
      assm.GetTypes()
      |> Seq.collect (fun ty -> ty.GetMethods())
      |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.Name <> "GetType" && x.Name <> "ToString" && x.Name <> "GetHashCode" && x.Name <> "GetType") 
    finally
      AppDomain.Unload(appd)
  with _ -> Seq.empty

let ListAllDlls = 
  let rec expandDir (parent : DirectoryInfo) = 
    let getAssemblyNameFromFile (f : FileInfo) =   
        try 
           [ AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName f.FullName ]
        with _ -> []
    seq {
        for f in parent.GetFiles() do
            yield! getAssemblyNameFromFile f
        for subDir in parent.GetDirectories() do
            yield! expandDir subDir
    }

  let basePath = "c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\\"
  let loc = ["GAC_64"; "GAC_MSIL";]
  seq {
    for l in loc do  
        let path = basePath + l
        yield! expandDir (DirectoryInfo(path))
  }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =   
  ListAllDlls 
  |> Seq.collect ListMethodsInAssembly
  |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%s" x.Name)
  0
```

Comment: Looking at the generated code for your `expandDir`, I don't see anything resembling CPS, but I do see a normal recursive call. So I guess it could blow the stack for deep directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

This function is not tail recursive:

```
let ListAllDlls = 
  let rec expandDir (parent : DirectoryInfo) accm =    
    let files = parent.GetFiles() |>  Array.toSeq |> Seq.map (fun f -> try Some(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName f.FullName) with | :? System.Exception -> None)
    let accm = Seq.append files accm
    let subDirs = parent.GetDirectories() |> Array.toSeq
    Seq.fold (fun accm d -> expandDir d accm) accm subDirs
```

Notice that the result of the recursive call to `expandDir` is used in the calling function (specifically in the function passed to `Seq.fold`.  This prevents tail recursion because the calling stack frame is still in use when the recursive call is made.

This is a tree recursion, so there isn't really a good way to make it tail recursive.  See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/08/13/recursing-on-recursion-continuation-passing.aspx) for information on solving this using continuation passing.  The essence of continuation passing is to maintain the list of branches you have yet to take as a lambda.